# Can i use multiple state value inside conditional rendering - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I wonder how can use two state based booleans inside of the conditional rendering . For example i want to render a certain `<div>` element if one of the conditions are truthy and otherwise don't render it 
Example :

```
{
 this.state.visible && this.state.checked &&
 <div>
  ...
 </div>
}
```

In order to display my error message i use this example , but init i have the `.length` of the object so it is easy to use like :

```
 {
  this.state.ErrorMessage.length > 0 &&
 <p>Error 404</p>
 }
```

Can somebody give me heads up ? I am a little bit confused .

Comment: To check if one of them are truthy you can use `||`: `(this.state.visible || this.state.checked) && <div>...</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow your way by parenthesis, to check both are true:

```
{
    (this.state.visible && this.state.checked) &&  <div>...</div> 
}
```

if you want one of is true:

```
{
    (this.state.visible || this.state.checked) &&  <div>...</div> 
}
```

Comment: Yep mate the second expression does the job !

Answer (score 0):

Use it as a separate function which returns the components based on condition.

**Example :**

```
renderConditionalComponent() {
  const { visible, checked } = this.state;

  if (visible || checked) {
    return <Component1 />;
  }

  // There could be other condition checks with different components.
  // ...

  return null;
}

render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderConditionalComponent()}
      {/* other components, etc */}
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The question was about the ternary operators .

Comment: @PandaMastr your question is about conditional rendering, not about ternary. You even accepted an answer that doesn't use ternary at all, you're not mentioning ternary in your question, etc. This answer is a valid way to achieve conditional rendering.